# Finding the MLEs of the Odds Ratio and the Log-Odds Ratio

Tags: probability, statistics

Take two random variables $Y$ and $Z$ with support $\{1,2\}$ each, and let
$p_{i,j} = P(Z = i,Y = j).$ We define the odds ratio to be
$$\psi = \frac{p_{1,1}p_{2,2}}{p_{1,2}p_{2,1}}$$
and the log-odds ratio to be
$$\gamma = \log(\psi).$$

I want to show that the MLE for $\psi$ is
$\hat{\psi} = \frac{X_{1,1}X_{2,2}}{X_{1,2}X_{2,1}}$
where
$X_{i,j} = \#\{Z = i \wedge Y = j\},$
and I want to show that the MLE for $\gamma$ is
$\hat{\gamma} = \log(\hat{\psi}).$

The MLE for $\gamma$ is trivial given the property of equivariance of
estimators. I do see that

$$\hat{\psi} = \frac{\hat{p}_{1,1}\hat{p}_{2,2}}{\hat{p}_{1,2}\hat{p}_{2,1}}.$$

Although this is again using equivariance of estimators. What I would like to
consider is how to get the MLEs for $\hat{p}_{i,j}, (i,j) \in \{1,2\}^2$.
However, I am having difficulty figuring out how to find the MLEs of
my data, since it seems as though the only realized random variable is
$X = (X_{1,1},X_{1,2},X_{2,1},X_{2,2}).$ How do I go about finding this
MLE?